# Obtener registro de la base de datos con ajax (usando un keyup) laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

estoy intentando que, al introducir un codigo postal, se rellenen automaticamente los campos de Localidad y Provincia.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label>Localidad</label>
                <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label>Provincia</label>
                <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label>Código postal</label>
                <input type="text" name="codigo_postal" class="form-control" id="codigo_postal" maxlength="5" required>
            </div>
        </div>
```

La tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ruta:

```
use App\PostalCode;

Route::get('facturacion/guardar/{codigo_postal}', function($codigo_postal) {
    $cp = Categoria::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)->first();
    $postal_code = $cp->codigo_postal;
    return response(['estado' => true,
        'postal_code' => $postal_code]);
})->name('postal_code.get');
```

La peticion ajax por jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var codigo_postal = $('#codigo_postal');
    var localidad = $('#localidad');
    var provincia = $('#provincia');
    codigo_postal.keyup(function () {
        var value = codigo_postal.val();
        if (value.length == 5) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'facturacion/guardar/' + value,
                method:'GET'
            }).done(function(res){
                alert(res)
            });
        }
    })



});
```

Por alguna extraña razon, cuando hago el alert de "res" me sale todo el código html de la pagina... alguien me puede ayudaR? muchas gracias!

Comment: Tienes en algún lugar otra ruta que encaja con esa url, no tendrás por ejemplo un `facturacion/**` que devuelve el index? Las rutas suelen ponerse de más específica a menos específica para evitar este tipo de problemas.

Comment: probé a añadir una URL completamente distinta que no tuviese nada, y aun asi me pasa lo mismo.. @Benito-B